# Here geocoding API returns 401 Unauthorized when calling from Google Cloud

Tags: here-api, http-status-code-401

I was using Google cloud to call Here Geocoding API and got 401 Unauthorized. However, when I print out the request URI and visit it manually, I can get the correct Geocoding response. Is that because Google cloud ips are blacklisted on the service side?

I used the correct app_id and app_code in the request.

Comment: I'm facing the same on Android using the Bridge library. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No we decided to use Google/Mapbox geocoding instead.

Comment: In my case the problem turned out to be a bug in Bridge which resulted in adding unsolicited headers. ps: I fixed the problem in [this PR](https://github.com/afollestad/bridge/pull/38) for those who might be interested

Answer (score 0):

401 error could be returned from HERE APIs if the header parameter **"referrer"** has a value which is not white-listed for the credentials. Either remove domain white-listing for the credentials from HERE Developer portal dashboard or update the header value to match the domain white-listed for the credentials.

Comment: I am on a freemium plan. Could you please guide me through -  removing domain white-listing for the credentials from HERE Developer portal dashboard. I am getting a similar error